# ¿Cómo hacer un update de una base de datos a otra más rápido con mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

He elaborado un código simple para pasar datos de una base de datos a otra donde una columna de números no únicos de una tabla es igual a la columna de otra tabla (como un v-lookup de excel). Mi código es este:

```
UPDATE 
    supplies_genuine_k_value, reseller_map
SET
    supplies_genuine_k_value.map_reseller = reseller_map.name
WHERE 
    supplies_genuine_k_value.reseller_key = reseller_map.id_customer;
```

El problema es que supplies_genuine_k_value tiene 80.000 filas y reseller_map tiene 20.000 filas. Al MySQL le cuesta muchísimo tiempo (horas) en ejecutar esta simple acción. ¿Cómo hacerlo más rápido?

Comment: Crea indices en reseller_key y id_customer para que haga más rapido la comparacion.

Comment: Gracias @Roy ahora lo intento y te digo el resultado. Gracias.

Comment: 56978 rows affected. (Query took 5.5091 seconds.) SUUUUPER !!!!!

Comment: Genial, buena suerte!

Comment: Graciaaaaas !!!

Comment: @Roy podrías poner tu comentario como respuesta para marcar esta pregunta como resuelta

Comment: Lukas, crea indices en reseller_key y id_customer para que haga más rapido la comparacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El comentario de @Roy me ha resuelto la pregunta:

> Crea indices en reseller_key y id_customer para que haga más rapido la
>   comparacion.

He creado los índices con este código:

```
ALTER TABLE `supplies_genuine_k_value` ADD INDEX `reseller_key` (`reseller_key`);

ALTER TABLE `reseller_map` ADD INDEX `id_customer` (`reseller_key`);
```

Y el resultado ejecutando mi código inicial de UPDATE fue este: (Query took 5.5091 seconds.) Increíble.